# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: python, django

El tema es que no me encuentra la imagen(Zappy.jpg) que tengo como ruta estática y no sé por qué . El código a continuación se llama ***home.html*** (está dentro de templates/portfolio)

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'portfolio/Zappy.jpg' %}"> #no detecta la imagen

{% for project in projects %}
   <h2> {{ project.title }} </h2>
   <p>{{ project.description }} </p>
   <img src="{{project.image.url}}">
   
   {% if project.url %}
   <br>
   <a href="{{project.url}}">Link</a>
   {% endif %}
 
{% endfor %}
```

En mi ***settings.py*** tengo esto:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Y la ***ruta de carpetas*** es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es porque en codigo tienes:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Entonces django va a buscar o incrustar imagenes en el archivo media, y tu estas buscando en el archivo static, una solucion podria ser:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/portfolio')
```

O crear un archivo media y guardar y buscar todo desde ese archivo, para mas informacion puedes buscar en https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#media-root